# JS Modal- Not using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I use an anchor tag instead of a button to trigger the modal?  I can't use Bootstrap because I need to modify the size of the modal. I tried putting the ID in the href but that didn't help.  Any suggestions?

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
     
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: try to use `btn.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();modal.style.display = "block";
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you simply change the existing `<button>` tag to `<a>` then your existing JS code should work. The principle is exactly the same, to get a reference to the element by ID and then attach a click handler.

But to get the anchor to display as a link it needs an href, so I've used `href="#"`, and then updated the click function to cancel the default click behaviour.

You probably also want some CSS to hide the modal initially.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // ADDED this line
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
#myModal { display: none; }  /* added this CSS */
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<a id="myBtn" href="#">Open Modal</a>  <!-- changed tags, added href, kept id -->

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
     
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Even though your answer works, it's kind of wrong to use an anchor tag. If you look into accessible and semantically correct code you should use anchor tags for anchors to other pages. Going with a button is the way to go if you are worried about accessibility, since a button is used for an action on the page.

Comment: Thank you!  It worked, In my first attempt I used <a id="myModal href="#myModal"></a> .

Comment: @MickFeller - Sure, but I was just answering what was asked. Although note that linking to other pages isn't the only semantically correct use of anchors, it's always been fine to link to other parts of the current page with an `href` that references another element on the page. (No JS needed for that, of course.)

Comment: @nnnnnn you are correct internal links are also allowed. But in your use case it just won't pass accessibility test.

Comment: @MickFeller-  How would I add another modal to another link?                                                                
  <ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#" class="header">Automobile</a></li>
  <li><a id="modalBtn" href="#">Truck </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Car</a></li>